# Dynamically injecting React components and jsx files into a template file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have one file named `Template.jsx` and three files for components, i.e `Combobox.jsx` for a Combobox, `Slider.jsx` for a slider etc. Each component also has a couple `.jsx` files that show its usage and documentation

I am trying to dynamically insert my component code and its corresponding usage code into my template file.

Combobox.jsx

```
export default class Combobox extends React.Component {
    constructor() {...} 
    ...
}
```

ComboboxInfo.jsx

```
export default class ComboboxInfo extends React.Component  {
    render() {
       return (
           <div><h2>This is Info about Combobox </h2></div>
       );
    }
}
```

Template.jsx

```
export default class Template extends React.Component  {
        render() {
           return (
               <div>{ComponentName}</div>
               <div>{ComponentInfo}</div>
           );
        }
    }
```

Since webpack bundles all the code into one file, is it possible to get access to the file tree and loop through each component file so that I can inject it into the template file?

For example, 'Combobox' should be injected into the "ComponentName" div and all the rendered code in ComboboxInfo.jsx should be injected into the "ComponentInfo" div. This should then repeat for all the components I have.

Comment: By *"dynamically"* you mean getting component in the file through for example ajax in runtime and inject it in runtime in already mounted component?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your simply wanting to use one component inside of another component. If this is the case, you probably want to spend more time looking into react, as this is most likely covered in the hello world demo.

```
import ComponentName from 'components/Combobox'
import ComponentInfo from 'components/ComboboxInfo'
export default class Template extends React.Component  {
    render() {
       return (
           <div><ComponentName /></div>
           <div><ComponentInfo /></div>
       );
    }
}
```

If the "injection" you're mentioning is to prevent elements from being displayed, just add a conditional into the render method via JSX.

Something like the following would work in that scenario:

```
const displayComboBox = someBoolValue ? <ComponentName /> : null;
```

Hope this was of some help!

Comment: I know I can do it like this. The question I had was more about the code checking the files automatically instead of you having to manually import the components.Every time I write a new component I don't want to have to edit this template. It should just generate it. I hope that is more clear